# How to send data From activity to Fragment Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have referred  many code on this question , but can not get any help for my problem.
This is My code from where I want to send data to previous `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class AddTask extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);

    ImageButton position = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.select_position);

    position.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent m = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),
                    MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(m);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_task, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.accept:
        FinishActivity();
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.cancle:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void FinishActivity() {
    EditText activity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_name);
    EditText description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("activity", activity.getText().toString());
    if (activity.toString().isEmpty() || description.toString().isEmpty()
            || address.toString().isEmpty()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Field must not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me What to use in this code to send data, I have used `Fragment` class to send it but it make error in `Activity`.

Comment: pass data using **Intent**

Comment: What type of error you are getting? Post your logcat here!

Comment: How you are calling your activity from Fragment ?

Comment: Have you tried to Google it? Do you know what is the difference between `Fragment` and `Activity`? and when to use which?

Comment: What are you doing with the bundle object in FinishActivity() ?

Comment: Do you want to pass data to `MapActivity` ?

Comment: if you need to get data from 3 `EditText`s why not use a `Dialog` in your `FragmentActivity` instead of creating a new `Activity`?

Comment: Sorry for less information about problem and I got answer from @Pragna using Fragmentclass was telling to to add class named as Fragmentclass, but after importning Fragment to current activity it is solved. Thanks to everyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
> bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
> // set Fragmentclass Arguments
> Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
> fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
> ```

```
and in Fragment onCreateView method:



 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. This is same what i was doing but i never try to import Fragment into current activity. so it was telling me to make class of "Fragmentclass".